# How can I undo `TeX-fold-buffer` command?

Tags: latex

I am using [`TeX-fold-buffer`](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Folding.html), to make my `.tex` file more readible. But I am not able to reverse this operation, unfold this; hence, I have to restart Emacs.

After appying `TeX-fold-buffer`, how can I convert buffer to its normal look? I looked for `TeX-unfold-buffer` but I was not able to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do  `C-c C-o C-h`, this  is what you get.

Try  the `clearout` commands.

`TeX-fold-mode` Minor Mode Bindings Starting With `C-c C-o`

| Key | Binding |
| --- | --- |
| `C-c C-o C-b` | `TeX-fold-buffer` |
| `C-c C-o C-c` | `TeX-fold-comment` |
| `C-c C-o C-e` | `TeX-fold-env` |
| `C-c C-o RET` | `TeX-fold-macro` |
| `C-c C-o C-o` | `TeX-fold-dwim` |
| `C-c C-o C-p` | `TeX-fold-paragraph` |
| `C-c C-o C-r` | `TeX-fold-region` |
| `C-c C-o b` | `TeX-fold-clearout-buffer` |
| `C-c C-o i` | `TeX-fold-clearout-item` |
| `C-c C-o p` | `TeX-fold-clearout-paragraph` |
| `C-c C-o r` | `TeX-fold-clearout-region` |

`latex-mode` Major Mode Bindings Starting With `C-c C-o`:

| Key | Binding |
| --- | --- |
| `C-c C-o C-f` | `TeX-fold-mode` |
|  |  |

Comment: `TeX-fold-clearout-buffer` was what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

`TeX-fold-mode` (bound to `C-c C-o C-f`) toggles the mode and, when toggled off, clears any  folding in the buffer.

Comment: `TeX-fold-mode` differs from `TeX-fold-buffer` it does not apply the same behavior

Comment: Sure they are different: one provides the keybinds for the other.  But what I said is true: turning the mode off clears folding.  That said, the accepted answer is much better.

Comment: Sorry like I try to say when I use `TeX-fold-mode` it does not actually folds the buffer so instead I always do `TeX-fold-buffer` instead